# Ruby on Rail: "DocumentRoot /home/rubys/work/depot/public/" only list files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to ROR and currently following book "Agile Web Development with Rails v4".

According Iteration K1: Deploying with Phusion Passenger and MySQL (at page 233), I tried config the server using config below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName depot.yourhost.com
    DocumentRoot /home/rubys/work/depot/public/
    <Directory /home/rubys/work/depot/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I can see the server but it only shows the list of files in public folder (like below). And my public folder has no any default html file.

```
Index of
   Name Last modified   Size    Description
   404.html 2015-01-02 22:52    1.3K     
   422.html 2015-01-02 22:52    1.3K     
   500.html 2015-01-02 22:52    1.2K     
   favicon.ico  2015-01-02 22:52    0    
   robots.txt   2015-01-02 22:52    202
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.195 Port 80
```

Can you please give me some direction what I did wrong.

Thanks